# How can I set intervals between ticks? d3.js

Tags: d3.js

For example I have svg container with 800px width and 600px height.
I wand to add a tick every 40px, so it will be 20 ticks on x-coordinate (with numbers from 0 to 20) and 15 ticks on y-coordinate (with numbers from 0 to 15).

[here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMUPD.png)

How can I do it? I use d3.js v5

There is my code (with zooming and dragging):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}

.box, .reset, .x, .y, .board {
    display: block;
}
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.reset {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    z-index: 100;
}
.x {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
}
.y {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
}
.board {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
}

#board {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

path.domain {
    stroke: none;
}

g.tick line {
    stroke: #D3D3D3;
    stroke-width: 2;
}

g.tick text {
    fill: #C4C4C4;
}

</style>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="reset"></div>
        <div class="x"></div>
        <div class="y"></div>
        <div class="board"></div>
    </div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>

function isInteger(num) {
    return (num ^ 0) === num;
}

var width = window.innerWidth
    || document.documentElement.clientWidth
    || document.body.clientWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight
    || document.documentElement.clientHeight
    || document.body.clientHeight;

var svg = d3.select(".board").append("svg")
    .attr("id", "board")
    .attr("width", width - 20)
    .attr("height", height - 20)
    // .append("g");

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    // .scaleExtent([1, 32])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);

x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]).range([0, width]);
y_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]).range([0, height]);

    var x_axis = d3.axisTop(x_scale)
        .ticks(?) //I dont know what do I have to write
        .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
            if (isInteger(d)) {
                return d;
            }
        })
        .tickSize(5)
    var x_axis_group = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)")
        .call(x_axis);

    var y_axis = d3.axisLeft(y_scale)
        .ticks(?) /I dont know what do I have to write
        .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
            if (isInteger(d)) {
                return d;
            }
        })
        .tickSize(5);
    var y_axis_group = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, 20)")
        .call(y_axis);

    function zoomed() {
        var new_x_scale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x_scale);
        var new_y_scale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y_scale);

        x_axis_group.call(x_axis.scale(new_x_scale));
        y_axis_group.call(y_axis.scale(new_y_scale));
    }
</script>
```